# Android Studio consuming all the ram available

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, android-studio

I am using android studio on amd athlton 5150apu(1.6ghz quad core) with 4 gb ram and windows 10, whenever i compile a project the computer stops responding and android studio, jvm takes most of the available ram, I have already disabled cvs as suggested by others.
So I am thinking switching over to linux(ubuntu) environment for development purposes as linuxes are resource friendlier than windows , can anyone tell me will it worth the time and resources spent on switching environment and downloading everything on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except if you go on a really lightweight Linux distribution, you won't gain that much speed.
You can try to confine Android Studio in a virtual machine with a limited amount of RAM or find a software to limit RAM/CPU usage on Windows.